# What is the difference between Eclipse 3.7 and Eclipse 4.1?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-indigo

I see there are two main distributions of Eclipse going on - One is on 3.6, 3.7, 3.8 path and the other is 4.0, 4.1 path(http://www.eclipse.org/e4/).

I don't have clarity on what is the difference between these two distributions?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

3.7 (code name `Indigo`) and 3.8 are bug fixes and stability releases whereas 4.0,4.1,4.2 (code name `Juno`) are new feature set mature platform releases. Release 3.8 and 4.2 are going on simultaneously. You can find more on the eclipse project plans [here](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project-plan.php?projectid=eclipse). Juno specific plans can be found [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Juno/Initial_Working_Plan).

Comment: Code name of 3.7 is Indigo, 3.8 is Juno.
And 3.x also adds a lot of new features. 4.x is target to next generation IDE that has significant UI model changes.

Comment: @Kane: Juno is 4.2 (http://wiki.eclipse.org/Simultaneous_Release). Actually, eclipse "classic" downloads now proposes only 4.x downloads: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/

Comment: @VonC, I don't know Juno also is the code name of 4.2. In bugzilla Juno also means 3.8, at least for RT-Equinox component.

Comment: @Kane: nope, Juno is 4.2. The next major release next year (aka Juno) will be a 4.x one: http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/cdt-dev/msg21822.html, http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/linuxtools-dev/msg00895.html, http://wiki.eclipse.org/Juno/Initial_Working_Plan. More precisely, "For Juno, Eclipse 4.2 will be the primary workbench, but all (participating) projects will support and maintain a 3.8 based deliverable."

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse 3.7 or Eclipse Indigo and Eclipse 3.8 are mostly the stable releases where bugs in the previous versions were being corrected. Eclipse always focuses on runtimes, static and dynamic languages; thick-client, thin-client, and server-side frameworks; modeling and business reporting; embedded and mobile; Theses stated features were enhanced and placed with the future releases 4.0,4.1,4.2 also called Eclipse Juno. It had a very mature IDE UI. Eclipse has always been working in enhancing the features given to the Developers to expand their programming knowledge and implementation. To do so the Eclipse Project has been extensively working with a group of multiple teams to build a better IDE than what they have currently. The team always tries to bring in the best with every next release. In the same genre Release 3.8 and Release 4.2 are going on simultaneously. Still the best place to find this info is the place from where even I have referred it [Eclipse Official Website](http://www.eclipse.org/)