# Eclipse not starting GWT instllation

Tags: eclipse, gwt

I am running Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo) on RHEL5. I installed GWT plugin from https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-3.7, and it asked me to restart. But it didn't automatically restart, so I tried to start it from command prompt. But it is not launching at all, giving a message like :

**Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchActivityHelper$4**

So I tried to follow the instructions at [Eclipse(Indigo) launch failed after google app engine plugin install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546283/eclipseindigo-launch-failed-after-google-app-engine-plugin-install), which in turn refers to [this](http://expertdevelopers.blogspot.com/2011/07/eclipse-troubleshooting.html). But even though I have removed the `.log` file, it is still not launching and throwing the same error. Can naybody tell me what should I do now?

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546283/eclipseindigo-launch-failed-after-google-app-engine-plugin-install

Comment: Go through my question, this is the very link I said in my question that I have gone through...

Comment: have you killed the process from task manager ?

Comment: Heads up!!! Use Juno if you can http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200100/what-is-the-difference-between-eclipse-3-7-and-eclipse-4-1

Comment: Yep. I uninstalled 3.7 and used 3.6 instead...

Comment: Any reason for going legacy instead of Juno !!

Comment: No reason, except that the environment setup in my RHEL5 system doesn't allow that. I use Juno in Windows. Will check for updates, if allowed, I will upgrade to RHEL5 on Linux also..:)

Answer (score 1):

We are successfully using Juno Eclipse with GWT 2.5 and GPE -

Juno - SR 1 http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

GPE - http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2

Reference - https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/getting_started